# project based SQL server database creation within a company

Tags: sql-server, database

My company wants to create a SQL server database for a long-term research project. My question might be a little open-ended but i only need a direction really.
I can create a stand-alone database within SQL Studio and all that, but i am not sure how to connect/integrate it with the existing servers and/or if the networking guys in my company could help me with that.

Essentially my questions are:

1. How to integrate a new sql server database within existing company servers? I mean do i ask them to install the enterprise studio app in my system? Do i ask them to give e remote access?
2. How would the users be able to access the database once i create it? Easiest way

I am new to databases and trying to learn so these questions might be very basic. This integration part is giving me fits. I would greatly appreciate any help here.

Comment: Just ask them to give you a database with full permissions on it. The dev of the project can deligate accounts the permissions needed according to the principle of least privilege. If you wanna create a local DB for testing the go ahead and do that. It will be a great learning experience. If you wanna go live, talk to your IT guys.

Comment: **1.** `How to integrate a new sql server database within existing company servers?` You need to have CREATE DATABASE access to the SQL Server instance if "you" are to create the DB otherwise the DBA needs to create the DB or someone with appropriate access to the SQL Server instance otherwise. **2.** `How would the users be able to access the database once i create it?`. They'd need to be granted access to it via a SQL login, a domain account or security group in AD, or through some application that has access thru its nterface. Talk with your DBA and have them show you all this... easy peasy

Comment: So when i tell them to grant me access to create db and they do that on their end from the server system. How do i access it from my system? SSMS? What other specifications would they need/want to know?